# Huion drawing tablet user, encountering certain keys and functions not doing as advertised from tutorial videos

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, navigation

Equipment is LG Gram laptop, Huion pen tablet and a wireless 3rd party keyboard.

I'e emulated 3 button mice, and the numpad due to a slim 3rd party wireless KB

I'e watched a few vids on key remapping while trying to follow main modelling tutorials

i get sidetracked/slowed down by having to seek out key terms/functions/hotkeys not correlating to video tutorials etc..

Main keys giving me headache or sidetracking me are the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> keys I think.

They are my navigation / orbiting keys [<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> = zoom in out] [<kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> = pan]

it took me a few days to figure out and configure my tablet to also just navigate around instead of using a mouse.

So right now I dont if im encountering really out of date video tutorials pointing to 2.8 blender or im just using or following wrong shortcut / hotkeys?

Anybody using similar equipment and encountering same time consuming/sidetracking hurdles?

tutorials requiring you to download an addon also isnt helping, I also get sidetracked by amazing blender projects that pop up which sort of encourages you to spend days youtubing.

any ready encountered solutions out there for tablet and keyboard users?

main gripe right now is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> being my main navigation keys while theyre also in modelling and selecting commands.

( right now selecting multiple lines/loops/objects and finding out that blender isnt being responsI'e while also hunting and trying to figure out the jargon in blender as well is slowing me down and bought me here )

What am I asking for? has someone figured and remapped all the keys for a tablet user, is it as daunting or as big of a headache as I fear it might be. I dont want to be messing or remapping of functions I have no idea does what etc

hope someone understands my issue, taking me 3 days to simply follow a box and vase-making vid which is actually straightforward and easy! its the in-between research and other extraneous stuff

Comment: What OS are you in? The tablet's driver should provide you with the kit to map buttons to keyboard equivalents, as you wish.

Comment: win11.... im a little less stressed now, just worked out the box select and ive pinpointed the [shift] button.... i was working from a video tutorial... im using a tablet and maybe the video wasnt correlating to what was showing up on my screen due to being 3 yr old tut lol... and ive just gone and hunted down an uptodate blender 3.5 shortcut pdf